# Using jquery mask plugin for cellphone numbers

Tags: jquery, mask

I'm designing a form which contains some input elements. One of them is about cellphone numbers. In my form, first digit should be between 1-9  , other digits could be any number. 
Here is my jQuery code.I need a pattern in order to make this project work:

```
    $(".not-empty2").mask('Z99-9999999', { translation: { 'Z': { pattern: /*an expression comes here*/, optional: true } } });
```

Comment: it requires 10 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of strange but changing "Z" to "B" solved my problem.

```
$(".not-empty2").mask('B99-9999999', { translation: { 'B': { pattern:[1-9], optional: true } } });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will allow exactly 10 digits, no letters, hyphens or parens and that the first digit do not start with 0.

```
/[1-9]{1}\d{8}/
```

Comment: it didn't work. also i edited a mistake in code. as you can see, "Z" is a special word that could be specially edited. writing `[0-9]` doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark - Share with me a cell number, to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$(".element").mask('099-9999999');

// 0 means /[0-9]/
// 9 means /[0-9]/ optional
```

Hope it works. It was tested on v1.5.4 of jQuery Mask Plugin.